# Convert sql server datetimeoffset to C# datetimeoffset or datetime

Tags: c#, sql-server, reflection, type-conversion

I have a column with datetimeoffset data type. For e.g.

```
2018-02-19 10:08:53.8060711 +00:00
```

I am trying to set this value to the C# property having the same data type.

In my application, I am using reflection to set the properties into the model (can't avoid reflection)

Here is the sample code -

```
Type propType = typeof(DateTimeOffset);
string value = "2018-02-19 10:08:53.8060711 +00:00";
// Failing here
// {"Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.DateTimeOffset'."}
propInfo.SetValue(model, Convert.ChangeType(value,propType));
```

Please note that the code is working for other datatypes. For e.g.

```
Type propType = typeof(bool);
string value = "true";
// This is working
propInfo.SetValue(model, Convert.ChangeType(value,propType));
```

If we can assign this value to DateTime instead of DateTimeOffset, that would also work for me

Comment: `Failing here` what's the error you are getting?

Comment: {"Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.DateTimeOffset'."}

Comment: If the SQL Server data type is a `datetimeoffset`, why is the value in your example a `string`?

Comment: Its actually very tightly coupled, I get this value as a string from the previous code block but the value is not altered

Comment: Why aren't you using `DateTimeOffset.TryParse()`?

Comment: `Convert` happens to have no support for `DateTimeOffset`, and is not exactly transparent in how it approaches conversions in general. Consider just special-casing this: `if (propType == typeof(DateTimeOffset)) propInfo.SetValue(DateTimeOffset.Parse(value))`. But first, investigate if you are getting this value as a `string` to begin with -- in SQL Server, the data is typed, so if you use an `SqlDataReader`, you can read this value with the correct type instead of going through conversions. This is true even if you use reflection to set values.

Comment: For `DateTime` I suppose your code should work. For `DateTimeOffset` - `Convert.ChangeType` will never work.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert , Your suggestion for handling a special case can solve the problem but it was looking for a generic solution. Anyways, Please frame your answer and post it